# Run-State values within shape script EA

Tags: shapes, enterprise-architect

Enterprise Architect 13.5. 
I made MDG technology extending Object metatype. I have a shape script for my stereotype working well. I need to print several predefined run-state parameters for element. Is it possible to access to run-state params within Shape ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. It's not possible to write your own attributes section, let alone runstate parameters (unless you want to use an add-in function in your shapescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Geert already commented there is no direct way to get the runstate variables from an object. You might send a feature request to Sparx. But I'm pretty sure you can't hold your breath long enough to see it in time (if at all).

So if you really need the runstate in the script the only way is to use an add-in. It's actually not too difficult to create one and Geert has a nice intro how to [create it in 10 minutes](https://bellekens.com/writing-ea-add-ins/). In your shape script you can print a string restult returned from an operation like

```
print("#addin:myAddIn,pFunc1#")
```

where *myAddIn* is the name of the registered operation and *pFunc1* is a parameter you pass to it. In order to control the script flow you can use

```
hasproperty('addin:myAddIn,pFunc2','1')
```

which evaluates the returned string to match or not match the string `1`.

I once got that to work with no too much hassle. But until now I never had the real need to use it somewhere in production. Know that the addin is called from the interpreted script for each shaped element on the diagram and might (dramatically) affect rendering times.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunatelly, we are not ready to use addin due lack of experience.